# Confusion matrix logic

Tags: confusion-matrix

Can someone explain me the logic behind the confusion matrix?

- True Positive (TP): prediction is POSITIVE, actual outcome is POSITIVE, result is 'True Positive' - No questions.
- False Negative (FN): prediction is NEGATIVE, actual outcome is POSITIVE, result is 'False Negative' - Why is that? Shouldn't it be 'False Positive'?
- False Positive (FP): prediction is POSITIVE, actual outcome is NEGATIVE, result is 'False Positive' - Why is that? Shouldn't it be 'True Negative'?
- True Negative (TN): prediction is NEGATIVE, actual outcome is NEGATIVE, result is 'True Negative' - Why is that? Shouldn't it be 'False Negative'?

[image]

Comment: Stick to positive/negative for the test, and True/false for whether the test matches reality (actual outcome). Then it should be clear.

Answer (score 4):

A **confusion matrix** is a table that is often used to describe the performance of a classification model. The figure you have provided presents a binary case, but it is also used with more than 2 classes (there are just more rows/columns).

The rows refer to the actual Ground-Truth label/class of the input and the columns refer to the prediction provided by the model.

The name of the different cases are taken from the **predictor's point of view**.

True/False means that the prediction is the same as the ground truth and Negative/Positive refers to what was the prediction.

**The 4 different cases in the confusion matrix:**

True Positive (TP): The model's prediction is "Positive" and it is the same as the actual ground-truth class, which is "Positive", so this is a True Positive case.

False Negative (FN): The model's prediction is "Negative" and it is wrong because the actual ground-truth class is "Positive", so this is a False Negative case.

False Positive (FP): The model's prediction is "Positive" and it is wrong because the actual ground-truth class is "Negative", so this is a False Positive case.

True Negative (TN): The model's prediction is "Negative" and it is the same as the actual ground-truth class, which is "Negative", so this is a True Negative case.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you understand the meaning of the confusion matrix, but not the logic used to name its entries!

Here are my 5 cents:

The names are all of this kind:

```
<True/False> <Positive/Negative>
     |                |
   Part1            Part2
```

1. The first part explains if the prediction was right or not. If you have only *True Positive* and *True Negative* your model is perfect. If you have only *False Positive* and *False Negative* your model is really bad.
2. The second part explains the prediction of the model.

So:

- **False Negative (FN)**: the prediction is NEGATIVE (0) but the first part is False, this means that the prediction is wrong (should have been POSITIVE (1)).
- **False Positive (FP)**: the prediction is POSITIVE (1) but the first part is False, this means that the prediction is wrong (should have been NEGATIVE (0)).
- **True Negative (TN)**: prediction is NEGATIVE and the first part is True. The prediction is right (model predicted NEGATIVE, for NEGATIVE samples)

Answer (score 3):

Please find the below:

- **False Negative (FN)**: prediction is NEGATIVE, actual outcome is POSITIVE, result is 'False Negative' - Why is that? Shouldn't it be 'False Positive'? 
  Answer : The predictive model supposed to give the answer as 'Positive', but it predicted as 'Negative', which means Falsely predicted as Negative aka False Negative.
- **False Positive (FP)**: prediction is POSITIVE, actual outcome is NEGATIVE, result is 'False Positive' - Why is that? Shouldn't it be 'True Negative'? 
  Answer : The predictive model supposed to give the answer as 'Negative', but it predicted as 'Positive', which means Falsely predicted as Positive aka False Positive.
- **True Negative (TN)**: prediction is NEGATIVE, actual outcome is NEGATIVE, result is 'True Negative' - Why is that? Shouldn't it be 'False Negative'? 
  Answer : The predicted output supposed to be Negative, and model also predicted as Negative.

For better understanding, you can run a simple binary classfication model and analyze the confusion matrix.

Thank you,
KK

Answer (score 1):

> True means Correct, False means Incorrect.

True Positive (TP): Model predicted P, which is Correct.

False Positive (FP): Model predicted P, which is Incorrect, must have predicted N.

True Negative (TN): Model predicted N, which is Correct.

False Negative (FN): Model predicted N, which is Incorrect, must have predicted P.