# What are true positive, false positive, true negative, false negative in the given example?

Tags: machine-learning

Assume there are 100 images, 30 of them depict a cat, the rest do not.
A machine learning model predicts the occurrence of a cat in 25 of 30 cat images. It also predicts absence of a cat in 50 of the 70 no cat images.

In this case, what are the true positive, false positive, true negative and false negative?

Comment: There are some good answers in the following post: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47725/confusion-matrix-logic/47727#47727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming cat as a positive class,

Confusion Matrix:

> **TN | FP
>
>      FN | TP**

- **True Positive(TP)**: Images which are cat and actually predicted cat
  i.e. 25
- **True Negative(TN)**: Images which are not-cat and actually predicted not-cat
  i.e. 50
- **False Positive(FP)**: Images which are not-cat and actually predicted as cat
  i.e. 20
- **False Negative(FN)**: Images which are cat and actually predicted as not-cat
  i.e. 5

> Precision:  **TP/(TP+FP)**
>   Recall:  **TP/(TP+FN)**

Precision: 25/(25+20) = 0.55,
Recall: 25/(25+5) = 0.833